# Converting AVSpeechSynthesizer text to audio file (.CAF)

Tags: ios, avspeechsynthesizer

I would like to programmatically convert a string file, which would be spoken using AVSpeechSynthesizer into an audio file, a .CAF file if possible (to use with local notifications).

I would like to do this in the background, upon app initialisation without the user being aware.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Did you find anything here?

Comment: Sadly not. The project was put on hold.